# Cross-References to Listings

Tags: citing, code, quoting

I am writing on texstudio, and there is a part where I want to insert a code written by me. In another part of the text I want to quote that piece of code but I don't know how.
The code is written in this way:

```
\section*{Matlab Code}
\begin{lstlisting}
 code
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: For next time, please read and follow http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Caption, label=lst:code]
    code
    \end{lstlisting}
    
    See Listing~\ref{lst:code}.

\end{document}
```

Set the caption and label as optional arguments to the `lstlisting` environment. This will produce code with the caption `Listing 1:Caption` and can be referenced later as `\ref{lst:code}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the label you can later use with `\autoref` (or `\ref`, or whatever you use to reference):

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={caption_text}\label{lst:a_label}]
code
\end{lstlisting}
```

By the way, I'm in the process of migrating my TeX codebases away from `lstlisting` to `minted`, mostly for reasons of robustness, and because I like the underlying code formatting abilities better.

Comment: `minted` relies on a 3rd party application, right?

Comment: Yes, just like `lstlisting` depends on a third-party LaTeX module. The difference is that writing a parser for many languages is much easier in other languages than TeX these days, so that solution quickly comes desirable.